# Database.EnsureCreated not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm playing around with Entity Framework 7 versions listed below

```
"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
```

My DatabaseContext class is very simple

```
public class WorldContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Trip> Trip { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Stop> Stop { get; set; }

    public WorldContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connectionString = Startup.Configuration["Data:WorldContextConnection"];

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

I'm experiencing a problem when hitting the `Database.EnsureCreated` method in the constructor. As far as I can understand, this method is supposed to make ensure that the database is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is supposed to do nothing. When I debug through my DatabaseContext class code I hit the breakpoint set on the `Database.EnsureCreated` method, when execution continues the breakpoint is hit a second time (This was not expected), so the DatabaseContext constructor is entered into twice for some reason. On the second hit the following exception is thrown

[image]

Even if the database exist, shouldn't the `EnsureCreated` method ignore it? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not call ensure created in your constructor, but call it once during app start